# c# endianness and structure

Tags: c#, endianness, byte-shifting

im trying to get some packet from microcontroller to c# program:

i defined a structure in both places. i calculate crc32 of (sizeof(packet)-4bytes) and place it in mydata_t.crc32 ...

```
struct mydata_t
{
    public byte cmd;
    public UInt32 param;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    public Char[] str_buf;
    public UInt32 crc32;
}

    private byte[] getBytes(mydata_t str)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return arr;
    }
    private mydata_t fromBytes(byte[] arr)
    {
        mydata_t str = new mydata_t();
        str.str_buf = new char[10];
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);

        str = (mydata_t)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, str.GetType());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return str;
    }

public static UInt32 xcrc32(byte[] buf, int len)
{
    UInt32 crc = DefaultSeed;
    UInt32 counter = 0;
    while (len-- > 0)
    {
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ defaultTable[((crc >> 24) ^ buf[counter]) & 255];
        counter++;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

my CRC function takes bytes and length .. so when i recieve data.. "in bytes" i convert them to structure by using (`private mydata_t fromBytes(byte[] arr)`)

**The problem:**
when i convert to byte array from the structure, calculating CRC is wrong "i believe its because of the endianness of the data types in c#? how do i solve this issue ?

here what i send from microcontroller:

```
    mydata_t datablockTX;
    datablockTX.cmd = 2;
    datablockTX.param = 0x98765432;
    memcpy(datablockTX.str_buf,"hellohell",10);
    datablockTX.crc32 = xcrc32((char*) &datablockTX,sizeof(datablockTX) - sizeof(uint32_t)); 
    usb_write_buf((uint8_t*) &datablockTX,sizeof(datablockTX));
```

here what i recieved and printed:

```
Data Received:
    CMD: 2
    param: 2557891634
    str: hellohell
    crc: 658480750
```

and then the **problem**:

```
public bool ValidateCRC()
{
    bool myvalidate;
    UInt32 mycrc_val;
    byte[] mybytes = getBytes(myblock);
    mycrc_val = Crc32.Crc32Algorithm.xcrc32(mybytes, mybytes.Length- sizeof(UInt32));
    //mycrc_val = Crc32.Crc32Algorithm.xcrc32(mybytes, 1);
    myvalidate = (mycrc_val == myblock.crc32);
    Console.WriteLine("c#:" + mycrc_val + " - MCU:" + myblock.crc32 + " - bool:" + myvalidate);
    return myvalidate;
}
```

this is what it prints in console:
**c#:667986744 - SAM:658480750 - bool:False**

---

i tried this in MCU:

```
        mydata_t datablockTX;
        datablockTX.cmd = 2;
        datablockTX.param = 0x98765432;
        memcpy(datablockTX.str_buf,"hellohello",10);
        //datablockTX.crc32 = xcrc32((char*) &datablockTX,sizeof(datablockTX) - sizeof(uint32_t)); 
        datablockTX.crc32 = xcrc32((char*) &datablockTX, 5); 
        usb_write_buf((uint8_t*) &datablockTX,sizeof(datablockTX));
```

here it what i recieved:

> CMD: 2
>
> param: 2557891634
>
> str: hellohello
>
> crc: 1993296691

in c#:

```
            byte[] mybytes = getBytes(myblock);
        //mycrc_val = Crc32.Crc32Algorithm.xcrc32(mybytes, mybytes.Length- sizeof(UInt32));
        mycrc_val = Crc32.Crc32Algorithm.xcrc32(mybytes, 5);
        myvalidate = (mycrc_val == myblock.crc32);
        Console.WriteLine("c#:" + mycrc_val + " - MCU:" + myblock.crc32 + " - bool:" + myvalidate);
```

**Console:
c#:146416248 - MCU:1993296691 - bool:False**

Comment: The problem could be even here: `public Char[] str_buf;`... Unless your microcontroller works with UTF-16 characters :-) Probably it should be a `public byte[] str_buf`. Note that there are various CRC32 algorithms... I hope you took the code from some code manual. And yes, endianness could be a problem.

Comment: i did convert it to byte still same, actually im printing it .. recieving exactly what im sending as text so i dont think it would be about the char encoding right?

Comment: Who knows? We don't know anything of your microcontroller.

Comment: im recieving the right data, only thing when i calculate the CRC in c# from the byte array from structure .. i dont get the right value.. i did test the crc function with some byte array defined by me in both mcu and c# and its the same result so its not in crc function "same function in both platforms"

i thought its something related to "structure padding of c compiler" ?? hmm but i dont think so because im recieving the values correctly..

Comment: What is the `sizeof(mydata_t)` in C?

Comment: sizeof(mydata_t) = 24
size of bytes arrived = 24
actually i did try to calculate CRC in mcu with length of (4) which should be
1 byte (cmd)
3 bytes from (uint32_t param)

and then calculate it back in the c# .. its not the same.. so thats why i though its because of endianness

Comment: It is not an endianess problem, that would also affect the `param` field value and it is correct.  So xcrc32() is wrong, no hope of getting help with that here.  Consider the shortcut, this data is sent through USB which already adds a CRC check itself.  So checking again is not necessary.

Comment: im using crc through usb right now but later it will be sent through different protocol that get noisy. i've checked xcrc with bytes it works ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public static UInt32 xcrc32(byte[] buf, int len)
{
    UInt32 crc = DefaultSeed;
```

to

```
    UInt32 crc = 0xff1fff1f;
```

The `DefaultSeed` you are using is wrong. (if you want to know, I bruteforced it... Tried all the 4 billion possible seeds). Works for both crcs you gave.

Comment: hello, the defaultseed is defined in c# and in c: 
uint32_t crc = 0xffffffffu; 
public const UInt32 DefaultSeed = 0xffffffffu;

Comment: @Hasanalattar Still with the seed I gave both the crc you gave (on 20 bytes and on 5 bytes) are calculated correctly... give some other datapoints to check.

Comment: you are right... why though ? now the seed in c# is different than c !!! ..

Comment: @Hasanalattar Have you discovered what the problem was?